# Unity3d does not open some windows

Tags: unity-game-engine

Some windows like Build Settings, Package Import (after downloading in asset store) don't load. It looks like the window didn't load yet, but only some white block is on it. Look the screenshot, you will understand.

P.S. Unity3D also looks the same if I run it without administator's rights.

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2mTO.png)

I have Win10 last updates.

Comment: Preferences also doesn't opens. I tried many builds of Unity, trust me and also I tried to restart my PC (of course).

Comment: In this order: reopen editor > reset computer > reinstall unity > format computer. One of those steps may solve the issue.